# Zeros of Riemann's $\xi(t)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

In Riemann's [paper](https://www.claymath.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Wilkins-translation.pdf) he defined $\xi(t)=\Pi(\frac{s}{2})(s-1)\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}\zeta(s)$, where $s=\frac{1}{2}+ti$. On page 4 he said:

> The number of roots of $\xi(t)=0$, whose real parts lie between $0$ and $T$, is approximately $=\frac{T}{2\pi}\log\frac{T}{2\pi}-\frac{T}{2\pi}$, because the integral $\int d\log\xi(t)$, taken in a positive sense around the region consisting of the values of $t$ whose imaginary parts lie between $\frac{1}{2}i$ and $-\frac{1}{2}i$ and whose real parts lie between $0$ and $T$, is (up to a fraction of the order of magnitude of the quantity $\frac{1}{T}$) equal to $(T\log\frac{T}{2\pi}-T)i$.

How did he compute $\int d\log\xi(t)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the integral

$$
\int\mathrm d\log\xi(s)\tag1
$$

is taken around a rectangular region symmetric about the critical line $\Re(s)=\frac12$, we can use the functional equation $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$ (the modern definition) to simplify the integral so that computing (1) only requires the calculation of

$$
\left(\int_{\frac12}^2+\int_2^{2+iT}+\int_{2+iT}^{\frac12+iT}\right)\mathrm d\log\xi(s).\tag2
$$

Because analytic functions have isolated zeros, we can choose $T$ such that no zero satisfies $\Im(s)=T$.

To compute this integral, we unambiguously can define $\log\xi(\sigma+it)$ by continuous variation from $s=2$ and $s=2+it$ to $s=\sigma+it$ for $\frac12\le\sigma\le2$ and $0\le t\le T$ so that

$$
\log\xi(s)=\log\left[\frac12s(s-1)\right]-\frac s2\log\pi+\log\Gamma\left(\frac s2\right)+\log\zeta(s)\tag3
$$

is valid on the path of integration of (2). Plugging (3) into (2) and apply Stirling's approximation to the $\Gamma$-function, we obtain

$$
N(T)={T\over2\pi}\log{T\over2\pi}-{T\over2\pi}+O(1)+R(T),
$$

where $R(T)$ is, up to a constant multiple, the remaining integral over $\mathrm d\log\zeta(s)$. Currently, it is known that $R(T)$ is of $O(\log T)$, so combining everything gives

$$
N(T)={T\over2\pi}\log{T\over2\pi}-{T\over2\pi}+O(\log T).
$$

For a detailed proof of this asymptotic formula, see my [two-year old blog](https://travorlzh.github.io/2021/01/19/zeta-zeros-count.html).